# Nginx: Remove duplicate slashes

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, nginx

Basically, I want http://www.example.com//index being rewrited as http://www.example.com/index

I already found a solution for this :

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*//") {
  rewrite "(.*)" $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

But I'm worried about the efficiency of the if statement.
I believe there is a better way to do it but I couldn't find it. I'd try this with no success :

```
rewrite ^/(.*)//(.*)$ $1/$2 permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)\/\/(.*)$ $1/$2 permanent;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Your example links didn't work for me.

Comment: It's just to show that I want a double slash "//" to be rewrite as a simple slash "/".

Comment: After reading the nginx regex documentation, I deleted my answer as I realized that the regex matches starting *after* the domain, so none of the issues I thought existed with your regex do in fact exist. I don't know why what you've done doesn't work.